# Multiple operations in a single transaction

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

A customer requested a very interesting thing. They'd like to have two operations - an update to the entity in the context **and** and update to an other entity to be carried out simultaneously.

In SQL, it's pretty straight-forward. One can simply roll-back the whole shabang if needed. However, I've never seen it done in CRM. Is it at all possible?!

Please note that I'm looking for a solution that is based on a supported approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simultaneously may not be the right word, but you can do it in the same database transaction just by updating the 2nd entity within a plugin operating on the 1st transaction in the pre or post operation event as long you use the IOrganizationService provided in the plugin context.

Throwing any kind of exception will "bubble up" causing the entire transaction to get rolled back (assuming you're not catching and "eating" the exception)

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks, mate! However, I'm not sure what you mean by "*or post operation*".

Comment: There are 3 plugins states to register a plugin for.  Prevalidation (before CRM does validation and before any database transaction), pre-operation within the database transaction, but before the entity has done Any CRUD operation), and post-operation (within the database transaction but after the crud operation)

Comment: Dude, I must be going blind... I'd swear that there was "*in the or post operation*". Too tired or something...

Comment: By the way - I need a clarification. Suppose that I'm running a plugin and in there I make changes to two instances. Can I be guaranteed that there won't be any mishaps if e.g. Scribe writes/reads to one of them? Does the DB lock the records during the whole plugin execution?

Comment: yes there is not any sort of magic going on. When the initial plugin runs a database transaction is begun.  As long as you use that IOrganizationService from the plugin context you're guaranteed to be executing within the database transaction.

Comment: @KonradViltersten oh and you are not going crazy. It's the weekend and I answered your question with my phone and didn't catch my grammatical error. I fixed it and you can see your phantom error in The edit log.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using early bound and the [OrganizationServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationservicecontext.aspx) you can add several objects to it and then run a "SaveChanges()" on the context to save all changes in one call.

Comment: This isn't actually transactional though, if one of the operations fails the rest are still commited. The only way to ensure reliable transactions is to do it in the plugin pipeline as described in the answer

Comment: My bad, was getting the impression that they were linked somehow but when I read a bit more closely it doesn't say that.

Comment: Sorry, mate. Late bound as per requirement. :)